# Comma separated codes will not work on Android Softkeyboard example

Tags: android, keyboard

I am working on the SoftKeyboard example and cannot get comma separated codes to work.  Lines 1 and 2 below work and output exactly what I expect.  Despite the fact that the documentation says android:codes is the "unicode value or comma-separated values that this key outputs" lines 3 thru 5 don't work.  Line 3 and 4 output invisible characters, line 5 outputs only a single 5 when it should output two 5's.  When I Google I see lots of examples using comma separated codes too, so it must work for some folks, i just can't figure out why it won't work for me.  I needs codes to work, because keyOutputText won't work with keyIcon, only keyLabel.  Thanks for your help.

```
<Key android:keyOutputText="\uD834\uDD1E" android:keyLabel="1" android:keyEdgeFlags="left"/>
<Key android:codes="0x2669" android:keyLabel="2"/>
<Key android:codes="0x2669,0x266A" android:keyLabel="3"/>
<Key android:codes="0xD834,0xDD1E" android:keyLabel="4"/>
<Key android:codes="53,53" android:keyLabel="5"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

This question is 7 months old, but I'd like to leave an answer here for anyone else who comes along.

Comma-separating the values creates a list of outputs for the key, ala texting on a numpad phone, where each tap in a short time will swap to the next value of that key. When outputting a string of characters on a single press, you use android:keyOutputText="55" instead of android:codes="", it looks like the OP is going to be stuck with keyIcon.